# Is AWS batch right solution for running large number of very short tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-processing

I have to run a migration job, processing about 2 million records and the processing step for each should take about 10-30 secs. Is AWS Batch the right solution? Based on my understanding, it will launch containers for each job submitted.

Is it more efficient to run a poller on containers running in ECS and process all records?

Comment: So the run will take about a month?

Comment: About *a year*. 2M records * 15s = 30Msec = 347 days.

Comment: well, plan to run multiple containers. And thats the clarification I am seeking, the overhead of launching new containers for "each" job seems extensive. Multiple containers polling for job seems more efficient, say 1000 containers running in parallel?

Comment: Migration from what to what? I'd be tempted to look at writing one identifier per record to SQS and then have that configured to trigger a Lambda function with a given batch size (the max Lambda runtime of 15 mins means each Lambda invocation could handle ~30 records). Or reduce the batch size and raise the Lambda concurrency to reduce the elapsed time, assuming you can migrate records in parallel.